# Testing @RooJavaBean class in Eclipse IDE with JUnit

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, junit4, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use Spring Roo to generate getters/setters.
When I update my class under test and then run JUnit tests from Eclipse IDE (STS), it does't see changes I have made.
For example:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.web.forms.UserRegistrationForm_Roo_JavaBean.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_datefitting_web_forms_UserRegistrationForm_Roo_JavaBean$com_example_web_forms_UserRegistrationForm$setName(Lcom/datefitting/web/forms/UserRegistrationForm;Ljava/lang/String;)V`
```

After running `roo>perform tests` everything runs fine even in IDE. In project settings there is *AspectJ builder*.

How to run JUnit tests of *@RooJavaBean* annotated class in IDE, without invoking `mvn test` or `roo>perform tests`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Roo shell open in STS while you are running?  In order for your aspects to be recreated based on changes to the target types, the Roo shell must be running in the IDE.  If it is running on the command line (from outside the IDE), STS will not be made aware that changes have been made to aspects and it will not be picked up in your project.

Comment: Roo shell is open and running in STS. IDE is aware that changes have been made (syntax highlighting shows that method exists). Problem is when running tests from IDE. It seams that class have not bean recompiled.

Comment: Hmmm....interesting.  Can you confirm that if you do a full build pf your project, then you can run the tests from inside of STS?

Comment: Yes, after invoking full build (IDE>clean, mvn compile, roo>perform assembly or tests), I can run tests from inside of STS.

Comment: Sorry, I meant specifically, that all you do is run Project -> Clean from within Eclipse.   After doing only that, can you run tests?

Comment: Yes (those methods where run separately).

Comment: So, this is starting to look like a bug of some sort.  I'd recommend posting to the Spring Roo forum here: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=67 They can probably figure out if this is indeed a bug with Spring Roo, AspectJ, or STS.

Comment: [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=103670) Recreating project helps.