# Cannot proceed with Spring Roo: Advaned MVC Problems

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I was scheduled to begin work on a new project and decided to make my life easier by adopting a new technology that I had no experience with: Spring!

Specifically Spring Roo, and therein lies my problem.

Spring Roo does so much auto-magical stuff that I really do not know how to proceed. As this runs the risk of turning into a rant, let me be more specific and then follow it up with my question:

**Spring works great for setting up my classes and persisting them with Hibernate and all that**. The main problem I am having is in trying to scaffold my project.

**I am working on a project that manages a few "set" references with many-to-many and many-to-one relationships**. This immediately will have problem with the scaffolding application.

**Trying to add Google Web Toolkit  via 'gwt setup' kills the application immediately**. Trying to load in Tomcat server becomes impossible and there is no way to undo the process (as far as I know). Now what? I have to restart my project from the original commands and reapply my changes as far as I can tell.

With this being said it seems to me that the best process is to use ROO to generate my project artifacts and then create my own View/Controller setup. Even here I am having problems though, because the tiles configuration seems so obscured from how it works. I am having a hard time figuring out how to take a custom JSP that can process some of these complex many-to-one relationships (AJAX enabled) and add it to my web front.

Are there any guides for this?

FYI: in the existing Roo Generated MVC I tried

- Copying over my JSP
- Creating a Form Backing Objects that wraps the different entity types
- Modifying the views.xml file in the folder to recognize the page

One this was accomplished, though, I have been unsure how to proceed. How do I access my JSP? Manually typing the URL as it is defined in views.xml does not work.

Should I think about abandoning Roo altogether and starting a Spring project from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bet way to learn Spring Roo

- read documentation ([Spring Roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/), [enter link description here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html))
- experiment with Roo and watch console output. See files that change, what changes if you add new controller etc.
- read and discuss matters in [SpringSource forum](http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?67-Roo)
- follow [spring-roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-roo) tag in SO

Using Spring Roo for scaffolding

- user version control system or [backup](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#beginning-step-8) project. If result does not satisfies you - rollback changes.
- Eclipse or SpringSource Tool suite have have hiccups ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284496/how-to-use-junit-tests-with-spring-roo-problems-with-entitymanager), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985466/testing-roojavabean-class-in-eclipse-ide-with-junit)). Be aware of them. Use `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` and re-import project if necessarily.
- know the difference between [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architectural pattern, [Web MVC framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and [GWT](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#d4e2095) scaffold application.
- know limitations and behaviour of scaffolding ([ITDs: GWT Style](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#d4e2222), [Expected GWT Add-On Behaviour](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#d4e2244), [JSP Views](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#jsp-views))
- know how [Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) works, to use effetely in your views
- investigate request pipeline ([Adding a custom page in spring roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687282/adding-a-custom-page-in-spring-roo), [Adding new Activity in GWT scaffolded app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917703/gwt-rootlayoutpanel-problem-rendering-page-from-second-to-first-first-works-fi))

Comment: Thanks for the checklist. I will disagree with one point: posting in the forums. As of this writing they are pretty dead and trying to get an answer there is far less likely than getting one in SO.