# GWT RootLayoutPanel - Problem rendering page from second to first (first works fine)

Tags: java, gwt, spring-roo, uibinder

Sorry if this was already answered before. I did a little searching and found nothing that could solve my problem. I created an application with Spring Roo, then converted to a GWT app. 
All the code generated by Spring Roo is only for CRUD. Now i want to add a Calendar for make appointments, so i need to move to another page. 
I´ve added this code to
**ScaffoldDesktopShell.java()**

```
    public ScaffoldDesktopShell() {
            initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
                startButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new NovoPainel());    
                    }
                });
            }
...
```

Then created a new UIbinder, called it **NovoPainel()** and added this code:

```
public NovoPainel() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    botao.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {             
            RootLayoutPanel.get().clear(); 
            RootLayoutPanel.get().add (new ScaffoldDesktopShell()); 
        }
    });
}
```

Everything goes fine moving from my root panel to NovoPainel, but when i need to go back to rootPanel the page doesn´t render correctly.
EX: Doesn´t show ** ValuePicker ** to click on left panel and render on center.

This is my RootPanel
[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/martinhoarantes/5694616812/in/photostream]

and this image is when navigate from rootPanel to NovoPainel

[image]

and finally this one is returning from NovoPainel to RootPanel
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to integrate with Roo generated architecture so that you can still benefit from Roo scaffolding.

Roo generated code hides most of behavior in `_Roo_Gwt` classes and it is because [GWT doesn’t currently support ITDs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#d4e2222). So changes have to be made in derived classes by overriding methods from `_Roo_Gwt` class.

To navigate application use Places, ActivityMapper and ActivitiManager (you can find good read on @Thomas Broyer [posterous](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/) and [GWT help](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)).

If you take a look in `ScaffoldDesktopShell.ui.xml` - page is devided in three main areas.
[image: Roo Scaffolded Desktop Shell areas]
`ApplicationMasterActivities` class is responsible for master area.

```
masterActivityManager.setDisplay(shell.getMasterPanel());
```

`proxyListPlacePicker` in `ScaffoldDesktopApp.init()` generates place change event with apropriate `ProxyListPlace`.

```
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<ProxyListPlace> event) {
    placeController.goTo(event.getValue());
}
```

`ApplicationMasterActivities` class creates appropriate Activity in Master area by checking `EntityProxy` type contained in `ProxyListPlace` object.

```
public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
    if (!(place instanceof ProxyListPlace)) {
        return null;
    }
    ProxyListPlace listPlace = (ProxyListPlace) place;
    return new ApplicationEntityTypesProcessor<Activity>() {

        @Override
        public void handlePet(PetProxy isNull) {
            setResult(new PetListActivity(requests, ScaffoldApp.isMobile() ? PetMobileListView.instance() : PetListView.instance(), placeController));
        }

        @Override
        public void handleOwner(OwnerProxy isNull) {
            setResult(new OwnerListActivity(requests, ScaffoldApp.isMobile() ? OwnerMobileListView.instance() : OwnerListView.instance(), placeController));
        }
    }.process(listPlace.getProxyClass());
}
```

Navigation is created by listing all EntityProxy's in `ScaffoldApp` class

```
protected HashSet<ProxyListPlace> getTopPlaces() {
    Set<Class<? extends EntityProxy>> types = ApplicationEntityTypesProcessor.getAll();
    HashSet<ProxyListPlace> rtn = new HashSet<ProxyListPlace>(types.size());

    for (Class<? extends EntityProxy> type : types) {
        rtn.add(new ProxyListPlace(type));
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

To output meaningfull name in navigation menu they are rendered using `ApplicationListPlaceRenderer`

```
public String render(ProxyListPlace object) {
    return new ApplicationEntityTypesProcessor<String>() {

        @Override
        public void handlePet(PetProxy isNull) {
            setResult("Pets");
        }

        @Override
        public void handleOwner(OwnerProxy isNull) {
            setResult("Owners");
        }
    }.process(object.getProxyClass());
}
```

So you have to create new Activity.
public class SomeActivity extends Composite implements Activity{

```
private static SomeActivityUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(SomeActivityUiBinder.class);

interface SomeActivityUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, SomeActivity> {
}

private AcceptsOneWidget display;

public SomeActivity() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@Override
public String mayStop() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    onStop();

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    this.display.setWidget(null);
}

@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
    this.display = panel;
    this.display.setWidget(this);
}

}


<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
   <g:HTMLPanel>
    Hello world!
   </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Create appropriate EntityProxy. It is only to obey `ProxyListPlace` mechanism.

```
public interface SomeEntityProxy extends EntityProxy {
}
```

Create SomeActivity in A

```
@Override
public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
    if (!(place instanceof ProxyListPlace)) {
        return null;
    }
    Activity activity = super.getActivity(place);
    if (activity == null) {
        ProxyListPlace listPlace = (ProxyListPlace) place;
            if (SomeEntityProxy.class.equals(listPlace.getProxyClass())) {
                 activity = new SomeActivity();
            }
     }
     return activity;
}
```

Add place to navigation in `ScaffoldApp` or override getTopPlaces in derived class.

```
rtn.add(new ProxyListPlace(SomeEntityProxy.class));
```

Set correct menu rendering text in `ApplicationListPlaceRenderer`

```
@Override
public String render(ProxyListPlace object) {
    String label = super.render(object);
    if(label == null) {
         if (SomeEntityProxy.class.equals(object.getProxyClass())) {
             label = "Some activity";
         }
     }
     return label;
}
```

[Code in GitHub](https://github.com/abele/newactivity).

Comment: Thanks janis for your reply. I´m not yet prepared to do that changes. MVP is a new  approach for me. I´m going to explore first the gwt help for Activities and Places, and then i´ll be back to my project again. If you could post some code with the changes it would be great. If i get the correct answer i´ll post here.

Comment: Thanks janis.abele. You saved my day. Thank you for explanation and for having provided the code.
Your reply was very helpful and I'm sure that will help other colleagues with the same problem.

Comment: @Martinho From your example there is another detail - NovoPainel goes full-page so navigation seems to be nested, but this case is discussed in [GWT 2.1 Activities – nesting? YAGNI!](http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni)

Comment: Yes, but i think it´s not a problem. I was just testing and maybe i won´t need a full-page. I just need to implement a Calendar. That Calendar will be a drag and drop stuff. I need a stackPanel positioned on left, make async calls to server and get some stuff. Then drag an object from left stackPanel to MainPanel.

Answer (score 1):

GWT 2.1 introduced new classes that [implements the Model-View-Places](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) pattern (MVP).  This pattern (and the GWT 2.1 concepts) are heavily based on best practices from developers who have build scalable GWT-based applications, so many people are migrating in this direction.

Roo generates a GWT 2.1 application; all of its navigational code is built on top of Activities and Places.  The reason I bring this up is it sounds like you are attempting to side-step a lot of this navigational framework to implement your own.  I'm not sure, but I believe your problem is coming from the fact that the MVP code is getting confused as a result.

My recommendation would be to work through the GWT MVP article linked above first.  Do it completely separate of Roo, because the application that Roo generates is more complex.  Once you have a good handle on it, go back through the Roo-generated application and it will likely make more sense.

Comment: Hi Peter. I think you´re right. I started with Roo, spent a lot of time to get used to and i think it´s a fantastic tool. Now i think i have learned nothing. The MVP concept is a good approach but i think i don´t have time to put it all together (MVP from Standard Google project and Roo generated code). If you could just point me in right direction, for example show me some code and where i could change.

Comment: Spring Roo generates many files, most of them do not need them. It is very difficult to modify without changing any other file. I have 10 entities, each entity has a bunch of files and folders. I´m lost

Comment: So far in my experience I've used Roo to manage the server component of GWT projects.  It does a great job of removing the database-related coding.  Unfortunately, the GWT "Scaffold" application is pretty complex -- the intent is that you can use that as a basic data browser, but that you'll build your own UI.  You can still reuse a lot of the Scaffold app, but there isn't an easy way to modify it for specific purposes... it will always be a data-browser-like app.

Comment: Perhaps the best way for you to get started is to attempt to duplicate the 'ApplicationScaffold' GWT Module and its associated entry point, etc etc.  Then start modifying that to add or remove the UI components you want.  The good news is that the scaffolding can still handle all of the data loading & committing pieces... hopefully that's a decent starting point.  If not, ask more questions!

Comment: Agree with you about Roo, it´s an excelent tool to generate code (..database connection) and Data Browser. Still do not understand where I have to duplicate code because it is not difficult to navigate to the NovoPainel, but for the NovoPainel to RootPanel. Could you be more specific about what to change ... My Scaffolfing.java is ok   public class Scaffold implements EntryPoint {
 final private InjectorWrapper injectorWrapper = GWT.create(DesktopInjectorWrapper.class);
 public void onModuleLoad() {
  injectorWrapper.getInjector().getScaffoldApp().run();
 }

Comment: In GWT 2.1 apps, to tell the application to go to another location you call `placeController.goTo(otherPlace)`.  You'll need to create a new Place object, and a new Activity to populate that place with the data you want.  There will also be a View tied to that Place that incorporates the NovoPainel.  I don't think there's an easy short-cut here, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

You can create two div tags in your Porject.html file respectively with id firstdivtag_id1 and seconddivtag_id2.

Display first page by using

```
RootPanel.get("firstdivtag_id1").add(Panel1);
```

And then to switch over to another panel use

```
RootPanel.get("seconddivtag_id2").add(Panel2);
```